# What situations is RethinkDB ill-suited to?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-performance, rethinkdb

Rethink says this in their FAQ: "RethinkDB is not a good choice if you need full ACID support or strong schema enforcement—in this case you are better off using a relational database such as MySQL or PostgreSQL."

https://rethinkdb.com/faq/

One example of "full ACID support" is multi-document transactions (important in eg financial systems), but what else does it include? In what ways is RethinkDB not fully ACID?